# Actual chip size of Atmel ATtiny20

Tags: electrical-engineering

Atmel's [ATtiny20](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATTINY20) is 1.55x1.4x0.53mm in size. It is one of the smallest microcontrollers. What is the actual chip size inside it (i.e. without the packaging),like what is described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56649/what-is-a-die-package)?

Answer (score 1):

ATtiny20 is available WLCSP (Wafer level chip scale package) form factor, which is the bare chip with absolute minimum of padding required to mount it.

The summary [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8235-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATtiny20_Datasheet_Summary.pdf) on page 12 specifies for the WLCSP:

1.540 x 1.388mm Body, 0.433 mm thick.

Width and length will be exact match, but thickness includes the pads. A technical drawing on page 13 gives the chip thickness, although with tolerances:

min: 0.228mm, nom: 0.305, max: 0.330.

Assuming nominal values then, **1.540 x 1.388 x 0.305 mm**